# how can i put a variable in formulaire option in javascript

Tags: javascript, dropdown, selectlist

I am trying to fill a selectlist with javascript :

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      formulaire.choixType[i].options.length= 10;
      formulaire.choixType[i].options[i].value =i;
      formulaire.choixType[i].options[i].text =i;
    }
```

i have 10 selectlist (K from 0 to 9):

```
<div>
<select name="choixType[k]" id="choixType" >
  <option value="" selected="selected">---choose-</option>
  </select>
  </button>
</div>
```

how can i do this , thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an exemple here: https://jsfiddle.net/xctty5bd/1/

```
// get select element with id 'choixType'
var select = document.getElementById('choixType');

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // first you create the element <option></option>
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  // then you add value and text
  option.value = i;
  option.text = i;
  // and then you put option at the end of your select
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but i have more than dropdownlist, i have k dropdownlist and k is variant,

Comment: just use a simple loop to fill each select, it will be easy now since you know how to fill one.